# How to find the error which is causing a segmentation fault in a script run by cron job

Tags: php, linux, segmentation-fault, wget

I have a cron job that executes once per day:

```
0 20 * * * /usr/bin/wget --timeout=10800 -O /home/File.txt http://www.site.com/script.php
```

and so far all was fine, but recently I found out the script just stops.

I looked in the `/var/log/httpd/error_log` (it's a CentOS) and found this:

```
[Thu Nov 21 21:30:32 2012] [notice] child pid 8985 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Now, this means two things: the script was successfully running for about hour and a half, but then the segmentation fault happened. Ususally the script takes around 2 hours to complete, so it lacks around half an hour to complete it's job.

Now, I can't find the error which causes the script to stop even though I do have error_reporting turned on.

I'm wondering, is there some way so that I can find a potential error line which caused the script to terminate?

I did try google, and SO, ofc, and tried to achieve the same as on [this question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298619/cron-job-mysteriously-stopped-running/13318816#13318816) by doing this:

```
0 20 * * * /usr/bin/wget --timeout=10800 -O /home/File.txt http://www.site.com/script.php 2>1& >> /home/log.txt
```

but the log file is empty. I'm not so good at managing linux so it may be that my command is wrong in this cronjob, so please steer me right.

Comment: because the script is written in php and maybe someone could hint me in finding the error there.

Comment: Yes but on your machine you are executing wget, which is written in C. So you can only see errors from your local machine in the logs, not about remote servers. By the way, how do you even know the segfault belongs to this cronjob?
My log of a segfault specifies the name of the crashed process:

Nov 22 16:52:47 xdat27 kernel: [1205891.274914] a.out[3508]: segfault at 4006c0 ip 00000000004005f4 sp 00007fff088c1cb0 error 7 in a.out[400000+1000]

Comment: This cron job is actually run on the server itself. I know this pid belongs to this script because when the script ran I took a look at its PID from `ps` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
0 20 * * * /usr/bin/wget --timeout=10800 \
-O /home/File.txt http://www.site.com/script.php  >> /home/log.txt 2>&1
```

the 2>&1 part tells to send the STDERR to the same place as STDOUT.

Answer (score 0):

Cron sends the output of the command to the email of the user which is executing it.

For this system to work you must have a mail daemon installed, such as exim or postfix.

Also, you are asking wget to write a file in the /home/ directory, i presume as non-root, which means you can't do that. And if you are root you shouldn't do that.

Comment: the mail deamon is installed and I was receiving mails from this cron job on a regular daily basis, but as I said just few days back these problems started to happen - the script gets a segmentation fault and the cron job never sends the email

Comment: Is it due to the quite odd location where you are telling wget to download the file?

Comment: Nah, no. I have made the file writable to the user which runs the wget (apache), and as I said - all was working till few days (and without me changing the script at all). Now, I'm just trying to figure out how to spot the error which causes the script to exit abruptly.

Comment: When I do this: `[root@mail log]# dmesg | grep failed` I don't get anything.